# for loop index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, openxlsx

I'm building an attendance tracker script.

The goal is to build some functionality where the script loops through spreadsheet A and when it reaches a list value in the 'attendees' columns, it needs to loop through that list and find where the current string value equals another string value in spreadsheet B. It then needs to put 'Present' in that stings row where the it also has the corresponding 'session' column.

The issue that I'm having is that I'm getting this error with my current algorithm.

```
index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Here is my code

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#code that I may use later
#sheet.drop_duplicates(subset = [ 'Date', 'Name'], keep= 'last', inplace= True)

wb = pd.ExcelFile(r"C:\Users\MyUser\Folder\attendance checker.xlsx")
sheet = pd.read_excel(wb, 'sheet')
atndOvr = pd.read_excel(wb, 'Attendance overview')

#This fucntion will change the attending column from a string to a list
def createList(index):
    cell = sheet.at[sheet.index[index],'attending']
    cellList = list(cell.split(";"))
    return cellList

#looping methodology(where the supected problem is occuring)
for ind in sheet.index:
    print(ind, sheet['Session'][ind], createList(ind))
    attendees = createList(ind)
    for name in attendees:
        #print(name)
        if name == '':
            pass
        else:
            #I'm getting the error in the index string
            index = atndOvr.loc[atndOvr['Names'] == name].index[0]
            print(index)
            atndOvr.at[index, sheet['Session'][ind]] = 'present'
            print(atndOvr)
```

I've been trying to use a combination of the .loc and .at methods in pandas to locate the specific cell that I want to add data to. I'm using .loc to get the index of the cell in spreadsheet b where it equals the name in the list that I'm looping through. I'm then using .at to actually change the data.

I expected to have it grab the index (which it does) and the it just takes the session(which it does and then just mark present in the cell. Unfortunately it stops at cell index 27 and gives me the index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0, and highlights this variable-

```
index = atndOvr.loc[atndOvr['Names'] == name].index[0]
```

I've also tried inputting a print spreadsheet b action in the string and it prints the spreadsheet, but it again stops taking adding present to the cells and index 27.

The DataFrame looks something like:

```
      Name  Event A  Event B  Event C
0    Glenn      NaN      NaN  present
1   Madina      NaN      NaN      NaN
2  Valerie      NaN      NaN      NaN
3      Dan      NaN      NaN  present
4   Darren      NaN      NaN      NaN
5   Mariah      NaN      NaN      NaN
6    Sarah      NaN      NaN  present
7  Cameron      NaN      NaN  present
8   Hauser      NaN      NaN  present
9     Edna      NaN      NaN  present
```

Comment: The error is telling you that there are _no_ elements in axis 0, because it has size 0, so there are no valid indices. If your code uses `[0]`, you're assuming a size >=1. So: check your `atndOvr.loc[atndOvr['Names'] == name]` logic, and instead of directly accessing `[0]`, first check whether or not there's something _to_ access.

Comment: The error is occurring in the index variable, and on index 0 at axis zero, I can't provide the data set as it is a breach of confidentiality, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans do you know have any suggestions on how to check whether or not there's something to access?

Comment: As mentioned: check `atndOvr.loc[atndOvr['Names'] == name].index` first to see if there's anything in it, before you try to access its first element. Or preprocess your data so that you've already guaranteed that value is a list of at least length 1.

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual data it is impossible to say for sure, but the error is essentially saying that `atndOvr.loc[atndOvr['Names'] == name]` is returning an empty result (meaning, there are no matching names). Now you have to figure out why that is the case (that requires having and understanding the data).

Comment: is there a way to skip it if there's no matching names? I'm still a little new to this. Embedded withing the second for loop I added an if statement to try to solve for that, but I would appreciate some suggestion to make it more functional.